# Is REST suitable for document-style web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

RESTful and document/message-style seem to be two trends to implement web services nowadays in general. By this, I mean REST vs SOAP, and document-style vs RPC-style.

My question is how compatible REST is with document-style web services. From my limited knowledge of REST, it is utilizing http GET/POST/PUT/DELETE verbs to perform CRUD-like operations on remote resources denoted by URLs, which lends it into a more "chatty" and remote-method like style, aka RPC style. On the other hand, document-style web services emphasize on coarse-grained calls, i.e. sending up a batch like request document with complex information, and expecting a response document back also with complex information. I cannot see how it can be accomplished nicely with REST, without declaring only one resource for "Response" and using POST verb all the time (which will defeat the purpose of REST).

As I am new in both document-style and RESTful web services, please excuse me for, and kindly point out, any ignorance in above assumptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of REST is misguided.  This is not surprising nor your fault.  There is far, far more mis-information about REST floating around on the internet than there is valid information.

REST is far more suited to the coarse-grain document style type of distributed interface than it is for a data oriented CRUD interface.  Although there are similarities between CRUD operations and the HTTP GET/PUT/POST/DELETE there are subtle differences that are very significant to the architecture of your application.

I don't think you mean REST over SOAP.  It is possible to do REST over SOAP, but to my knowledge nobody does it, and I have never seen an article talking about it.

SOAP is usually used for "Web Services" and REST is usually done over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am glad to know these two can indeed work together, but still not sure how I should go about implementing it. Can you please elaborate more on the reason "REST is far more suited to the coarse-grain document style type of distributed interface"? Pointing to a simple example or the few valid information on the internet will be much appreciated.

By "REST over SOAP", I actually meant to say "REST is preferred over SOAP". I just edited my post to avoid the confusion. Am I wrong again to assume REST is at the same layer as, thus an alternative to, SOAP?

Comment: Regarding whether SOAP and REST are in the same layer, see this answer I gave to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225701/well-behaving-restful-client-interactions/1230610#1230610

Comment: Thanks. I found following sentence to be particularly enlightening: "Web services deliver data that is to be processed by a client application. RESTful interfaces should deliver content that will be rendered to the user." Since my interface is really intended to sync application information between server and client apps without rendering it to users, I probably should go with Web Service approach.

Answer (score 1):

REST is really meant to be used with documents as long as you consider your document a resource.

GET allows you to retrieve the document. Obviously.

POST allows you to create a document. No need for your API to require the full content of the document to create it. It is up to you to decide what is required to actually create the document.

PUT allows to modify the document. Again, no need to force the client to send the whole document each time he wants to save. Your API may support delta updates sent through PUT requests.

DELETE obviously deletes the document. Again, you can design your API so that deletes does not actually destroy every bits of the document. You can create a system similar to a recycle bin.

What is nice with REST and working with documents is that the server response contains every information needed to understand the response. So if a new resource is created, you should send its location, same if a resource is moved, etc. All you have to document is the data types that will be used (XML formats, JSON, etc.)

Standard HTTP methods are just there because their behaviour is already defined and allow clients to easily discover your API as long as they know the URI.

Comment: PUT is not supposed to do partial updates.  There is a proposal in the works for a new verb PATCH to do that.  Until then you need to use POST and a media type that is defined to support partial updates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very helpful. In my case, the data-collecting client needs to send up information about itself, like id/last connect time etc., as well as newly collected data. The response from server will contain updated server data/configuration. As I would like to accomplish the task in one single REST invocation, it looks the only feasible verb to use is POST, since I have payload data in both request and response. Do you think this is the right way of using REST?

Comment: (continuing comment above, due to 600 char limit) It seems to me a "more RESTful alternative is to use two invocations: a POST for request followed by a "GET" for response. But it really does not feel right. Besides, I do need to correlate each response document with corresponding request document.

Comment: I think POST is great for what you want. Your client POSTs a content to a resource and gets a response from this resource. This is what POST is intended for: send data for processing and receive a response.